# strange error with serializer and the json response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a profile model that I serialize and set fields using "**all**". The problem is that when I run it, I get the error that:

```
AttributeError at /api/accounts/profile/
'User' object has no attribute 'following'
```

I tried setting the fields manually and get the same error, but when I remove following from the field it runs properly and I get the normal JSON response, but all the fields show null instead of the data I set in the admin panel.

```
{
    "pk": 2,
    "date_of_birth": null,
    "bio": null,
    "profile_photo": null,
    "sex": null,
    "type_of_body": null,
    "feet": null,
    "inches": null,
    "lives_in": null
}
```

below is the code to the rest of the app

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    following = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='followers', blank=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="DOB")
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    profile_photo = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=300)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX, blank=True, null=True)
    type_of_body = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=BODYTYPE, blank=True, null=True)
    feet = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    inches = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    lives_in = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('pk', 'user', 'following', 'height')
```

views.py

```
class CurrentUserProfileAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request):
        serializer = ProfileSerializer(request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^profile/$', CurrentUserProfileAPIView.as_view(), name="my_profile")
]
```

Answer (score 0):

`request.user` returns an instance of the `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` (or `AnonymousUser` for any unauthenticated user) -- the requesting *user*, but you're trying to serialize it using the serializer for the `Profile` model (`ProfileSerializer`).

As the user does not have the mentioned attributes of the `Profile` model, all fields are being serialized with `null`. And the `pk` is the `user.pk`, which is present on any Django model instance (always refers to the used public key).